# Upsert multiple fields C# MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I want to upsert the complete document except `Id` field with `C# MongoDB official driver 2.4.4` 
From `API documention` I can create `UpdateDefinination` as shown below

```cs
var filter = Builders<Shipment>.Filter.Where(_ => _.ShipmentIdentifier == shipment.ShipmentIdentifier);
var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Shipment>() { IsUpsert = true };
var update = BuildUpdateDefination(shipment);
var updatedEntity =  collection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options);
```

This Code works fine with below `BuildUpdateDefination`

```cs
 private UpdateDefinition<Shipment> BuildUpdateDefination(Shipment shipment)
    {
        var update = Builders<Shipment>.Update.Set(_ => _.Carrier, shipment.Carrier)
            .Set(_ => _.Addresses, shipment.Addresses)
            .Set(_ => _.Attributes, shipment.Attributes)
            .Set(_ => _.CarrierCashOnDeliveryAmount, shipment.CarrierCashOnDeliveryAmount)
            .Set(_ => _.CarrierInsuranceAmount, shipment.CarrierInsuranceAmount)
            .Set(_ => _.CarrierRoutingError, shipment.CarrierRoutingError)
            .Set(_ => _.CarrierRoutingValue1, shipment.CarrierRoutingValue1)
            .Set(_ => _.CarrierRoutingValue2, shipment.CarrierRoutingValue2)
            .Set(_ => _.CarrierRoutingValue3, shipment.CarrierRoutingValue3)
            .Set(_ => _.CarrierRoutingValue4, shipment.CarrierRoutingValue4)
            .Set(_ => _.CarrierRoutingValue5, shipment.CarrierRoutingValue5)
            .Set(_ => _.CarrierService, shipment.CarrierService)
            .Set(_ => _.CarrierServiceAttributes, shipment.CarrierServiceAttributes)
            .Set(_ => _.CashOnDeliveryReference, shipment.CashOnDeliveryReference)
            .Set(_ => _.Currency, shipment.Currency)
            .Set(_ => _.DeliveryInstruction1, shipment.DeliveryInstruction1)
            .Set(_ => _.DeliveryInstruction2, shipment.DeliveryInstruction2)
            .Set(_ => _.DeliveryInstruction3, shipment.DeliveryInstruction3);
        return update;
    }
```

But the problem is `Shipment` has many fields that need to be update. So whats better way to update the all the property of object ?

I have tried to iterate all the properties of the object as below, but this is also not working

```cs
var updateSet = new List<UpdateBuilder>();
Type type = shipment.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
   if (!property.Name.Equals("Id") && !property.Name.Equals("ShipmentIdentifier"))
      updateSet.Add(Update.Set(property.Name, (BsonValue)property.GetValue(shipment) ?? BsonNull.Value));

 }
var update = Update<Shipment>.Combine(updateSet).ToBsonDocument();
```

I have been searching from the long time but not got any working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Collection.FindOneAndReplace()`? 
you can use it to replace the object and set the `isUpsert` property to upsert the document.